Formal evaluation of $\Bbb E_i[T_0]$ for Gambler's Ruin

(Gambler's Ruin) Suppose $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ is a Markov chain on $\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ with transition probabilities $$\begin{aligned}p_{00}&=1\\p_{i,i-1}&=q,p_{i,i+1}=p,\text{ for }i\ge 1.\end{aligned}$$ Let $T_i:=\min\{n\ge 0\mid X_n=i\}.$ Compute $\Bbb E_i[T_0]=\Bbb E[T_0\mid X_0=i]$ for each $i\ge 1$ depending on the parameter $p\in(0,1).$

My thoughts
Since we can only reach adjacent states, in order to reach the state $0$ from the state $n+1,$ we must first arrive at the state $n.$ I believe the following is true $\Bbb E_{n+1}[T_n]=\Bbb E_1[T_0],$ which would, in turn, imply the following: $$\Bbb E_{n+1}[T_0]=\Bbb E_{n+1}[T_n]+\Bbb E_n[T_0]=\cdots=(n+1)\Bbb E_1[T_0],$$ however, I'm not able to formally argue it using the strong Markov property at the stopping time $T_n.$ If the assertion is true, I can, then, apply the following theorem:

Suppose $S$ is the set of states, $B\subseteq S$ and $g_i:=\Bbb E_i[T_B]\in[0,\infty],i\in S,$ where $T_B=\min\{n\ge 0\mid X_n\in B\}.$ Then the vector $(g_i\mid i\in S)$ is the minimum non-negative solution to the system of equations $$\begin{cases}g_i=0,&i\in B\\g_i=1+\sum_{j\in S}p_{ij}g_j,&i\notin B.\end{cases}$$

Since, $g_0=0$ in my case, $g_1=1+pg_2$ and $g_2=2g_1$ implies $g_1=\frac1{1-2p}=\frac1{q-p}$ hence, $g_i=\frac{i}{q-p}$ if $q>p$ and $g_i=\infty,\forall i\in\Bbb N$ otherwise (?).
Note: I also considered solving the system on the set $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ and letting $N\to\infty$ as suggested here, but I couldn't find a pattern algebraically.
Question How do we formally arrive at the same conclusion if it is valid?

I am not sure about the notation.  Does $\Bbb E_i[T_0]$ mean the expected number of steps to reach $0$ if you start from $X_0=i$?  What would this mean if there is a positive probability you never reach $0$?

@Henry, $\Bbb E_i[T_0]=\Bbb E[T_0\mid X_0=i],$ conditional expectation. If $\Bbb P(T_0=\infty\mid X_0=i)>0,$ then $\Bbb E_i[T_0]=\infty.$

Your argument is correct.

You you consider the process under $P_x$ (starting from $x$) and subtract $1$ from it, then the resulting process is a Markov chain with the same transition function, but starting from $x-1$. Therefore the distribution of $T_{n-1}$ under $P_n$ is the same as the distribution of $T_0$ under $P_1$.

As for the calculation of $E_1 [T_0]$, condition on the first step. This would give you
$$E_1[T_0] = 1*q + p*(1+ E_2[T_0]) = 1+ p 2 E_1[T_0].$$
Therefore $E_1[T_0] = \frac{1}{1-2p}$.
How to show this formally? We present an elementary argument only relying on the Markov property, which is all we need as we are conditioning on the first step.
We denote the process by $(X_0,X_1,\dots)$ (time starts at zero).
We clearly have
$$(1)\quad E[T_0|X_1=0]=1$$

The Markov property gives that the distribution of $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$  (from time $1$ onward) under $P_1$, conditioned on $X_1=2$, is the same as the distribution of the process $(X_0,X_1,\dots)$ under $P_2$ (shifting time one step back and starting from $2$).
Since $T_0= \inf\{n\ge 1:X_n =0\}$, a function of the process $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$, conditioning on $X_1=2$, $T_0$ has the same distribution as $\inf\{n-1+1 \ge 1:X_{n-1}=0\}=1+\inf\{n-1\ge 0 :X_{n-1}=0\}=1+\inf\{m\ge0:X_m=0\}$ under $P_2$. As under $P_2$ this random variable is equal to  $1+ \inf\{m\ge 1:X_m=0\}=1+T_0$, we conclude

$$(2)\quad  E_1[T_0 | X_1=2] = 1+ E_2[T_0]=1+ 2E_1[T_0].$$
Putting (1) and (2) together we have
$$E_1[T_0] = E[T_0|X_1=0]q + E[T_0|X_1=2]p = q + p(1+ 2 E_1[T_0])=1+2pE_1[T_0].$$

You you consider the process under $P_x$ (starting from $x$) and subtract $1$ from it, then the resulting process is a Markov chain with the same transition function, but starting from $x-1$ I think I needed to be reminded of that by another person. Now, I've seen the proof you provided in the remainder of your answer. Since  $(X_{n+m}){m\ge0}$ is a $(\delta^i,P)$ Markov chain wrt $\Bbb P_i,$ I now only have to apply the theorem I referenced to the Markov chain  $(X{n+1})_{n\ge0},$ that is, I would analyze the first step in that $(\delta^i,P)$ Markov chain...

And obtain a new system $$\begin{aligned}g_0&=\infty\g_1&=0\g_2&=1+pg_3\g_i&=1+qg_{i-1}+pg_{i+1},\forall i\ge 3\end{aligned}$$ in order to conclude the part $(g_1,g_2,\ldots)$ is equal to $(g_0,g_1,\ldots)$ of the original system, and so on and therefore, prove $\Bbb E_{n+1}[T_n]=\Bbb E_1[T_0],\forall n\in\Bbb N$?

Because, it seems, in every new, say $n$-th, chain, new $g_{n+1}$ wouldn't depend on the previous $g_0,g_1,\ldots,g_{n-1}$ (which would also all happen to equal $\infty$) since $g_n=0$ and the states $0,\ldots,n-1$ aren't reachable from $n+1$ in only one step.
